# When using the Wikipedia API, how to retrieve the style sheets?

Tags: html, api, parsing, wikipedia-api

I am trying to use [the Wikipedia API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) to get HTML content from Wikipedia. I can't find the correct way to embed this. Since styles are not expanded, I woudld imagine I would need to specify the stylesheets used in the head of the HTML that embeds it.

How do I know what the correct CSS to include are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to add headitems in the api request, like so:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Doritos&prop=text|headitems

That gives you another xml node, the content of which you can plop in the HEAD element of your HTML.

Comment: This doesn't return any CSS to me, only scripts :/

Comment: headitems is now deprecated, I think the proper way now is to use headhtml : http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Doritos&prop=text|headhtml